# How to know the exact Knot on spline the game object is on in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, spline

I have used `Spline` to animate a `GameObject` I want to disappear my `GameObject` when it is on `Knot[4]` and re-visible it on `Knot[6]`. But I don't know exactly how to do this. Is there any way to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for [`SplineUtility.ConvertIndexUnit()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.splines@2.5/api/UnityEngine.Splines.SplineUtility.ConvertIndexUnit.html) . [`SplineUtility.Evaluate()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.splines@2.5/api/UnityEngine.Splines.SplineUtility.Evaluate.html) might also help, depending on what you need. For real-time tracking, I don't think you can avoid the dreaded `Update()` way of putting if-checks there. I haven't found any runtime events, unfortunately.